# Monomorphism in the category of schemes versus the category of $S$-schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a homomorphism of $R$-algebras.  If $\phi$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings, then certainly $\phi$ is an epimorphism in the category of $R$-algebras.  Is the converse true?

Similarly, let $S$ be a scheme, and let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of $S$-schemes.  Is a monomorphism in the category of $S$-schemes the same thing as a monomorphism in the category of schemes?

The reason I'm asking is I was reading the definition of a "free action of group schemes."  Let $H$ be an abstract group acting on a set $Y$.  We say that $H$ acts *freely* on $Y$ if the stabilizer of each point is trivial, or equivalently, if the function $(h,y) \mapsto (h.y,y)$ is injective.

Now let $G$ be an $S$-group scheme, and let $\rho: G \times_S X \rightarrow X$ be an action.  $\rho$ is said to be *free* if the graph morphism

$$\Psi: G \times_S X \xrightarrow{(\rho,\pi_2)} X \times_S X$$

is a monomorphism of schemes.  I was expecting the definition to just be that $\Psi$ was a monomorphism of $S$-schemes, since this is equivalent to saying that the group action $G(T) \times X(T) \rightarrow X(T)$ is free for all $S$-schemes $T$.  But the definition of free here seems to be something more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works very generally in any category.  Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $S$ be an object in $\mathcal{C}$.  Then given objects $a:A\to S$ and $b:B\to S$ in the slice category over $S$, a map $i:A\to B$ is monic in the slice category iff it is monic in $\mathcal{C}$.  Indeed, suppose $f,g:C\to A$ are such that $if=ig$.  Consider $C$ as an object of the slice category via the map $bif=big:C\to S$.  Note then that $f$ and $g$ become morphisms in the slice category, since $a=bi$ so $af=bif$ and $ag=big$.  So every pair of parallel arrows in $\mathcal{C}$ coequalized by $i$ gives a pair of parallel arrows in the slice category coequalized by $i$, and so $i$ is monic in $\mathcal{C}$ iff it is monic in the slice category.

Comment: Thank you.  This is obvious now that I think about it.